# Proper way of handling threads in kernel?

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, zombie-process

I've seen bits of scattered information all around, but I can't seem to get to one final answer. How do you clean up a zombie thread in kernel?

Just to make sure, and produce a final correct way of handling threads in kernel, I would like to ask this question more broadly. **How do you create, terminate and clean up a thread in the Linux kernel?**

What I have so far is this:

```
thread_func:
    exited = 0;
    while (!must_exit)
        do stuff
    exited = 1;
    do_exit(0)

init_module:
    must_exit = 0;
    exited = 1;
    kthread_run(thread_func, ...)    /* creates and runs the thread */

cleanup_module:
    must_exit = 1;
    while (!exited)
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        msleep(1);
    /* How do I cleanup? */
```

The closest thing I have found to the cleanup solution is [release_task](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/kernel/exit.c#L168), but I didn't find anywhere talking about it. I imagined since the thread functions are `kthread_create`, `kthread_run` etc, there should be a `kthread_join` or `kthread_wait`, but there wasn't. `do_wait` also seemed likely, but it doesn't take a `struct task_struct *`.

Furthermore, I am not sure if `do_exit` is a good idea, or if at all necessary either. Can someone please come up with the minimum sketch of how a kthread should be created, terminated and cleaned up?

Comment: I seem to remember that there is a kthread_stop, or kthread_should_stop, something like that.

Comment: @MartinJames, the way I understood, you either exit yourself (using `do_exit`) or poll `kthread_should_stop` until someone (`cleanup_module`) calls `kthread_stop`. I didn't find anywhere saying whether `kthread_stop` also cleans up the thread or not. What makes me wonder is that, if people (on the internet) suggest using either `do_exit` or whatever, shouldn't there be a way to cleanup the thread after `do_exit`?

Comment: By the way, [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/65178/) is what I talk about when I say I can't reach a conclusive answer. There are a lot of conflicting stuff out there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the "right" ways to do this is to have your thread function check if it `kthread_should_stop`, and simply return if it does need to stop.

You don't need to call `do_exit`, and if you intend to `kthread_stop` it from the module exit function, you probably shouldn't.

You can see this by looking at the documentation for `kthread_create_on_node` in [`kernel/kthread.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kthread.c) (extract from Linux kernel 3.3.1):

> /**
>    * kthread_create_on_node - create a kthread.
>    * @threadfn: the function to run until signal_pending(current).
>    * @data: data ptr for @threadfn.
>    * @node: memory node number.
>    * @namefmt: printf-style name for the thread.
>    *
>    * Description: This helper function creates and names a kernel
>    * thread.  The thread will be stopped: use wake_up_process() to start
>    * it.  See also kthread_run().
>    *
>    * If thread is going to be bound on a particular cpu, give its node
>    * in @node, to get NUMA affinity for kthread stack, or else give -1.
>    * When woken, the thread will run @threadfn() with @data as its
>    * argument. **@threadfn() can either call do_exit() directly if it is a**
>    * **standalone thread for which no one will call kthread_stop(), or**
>    * **return when 'kthread_should_stop()' is true** (which means
>    * kthread_stop() has been called).  The return value should be zero
>    * or a negative error number; it will be passed to kthread_stop().
>    *
>    * Returns a task_struct or ERR_PTR(-ENOMEM).
>    */

A "matching" comment is present for `kthread_stop`:

> If threadfn() may call do_exit() itself, **the caller must ensure task_struct can't go away**.

(And I'm not sure how you do that - probably holding on to the `struct_task` with a `get_task_struct`.)

If you walk the path of a thread creation you'll get something like:

```
kthread_create                                           // macro in kthread.h
  -> kthread_create_on_node                              // in kthead.c
    -> adds your thread request to kthread_create_list
    -> wakes up the kthreadd_task
```

`kthreadd_task` is set up in `init/main.c` in `reset_init`. It runs the `kthreadd` function (from `kthread.c`)

```
kthreadd                                                 // all in kthread.c
  -> create_kthread
    -> kernel_thread(kthread, your_kthread_create_info, ...)
```

And the `kthread` function itself does:

```
kthread
  -> initialization stuff
  -> schedule() // allows you to cancel the thread before it's actually started
  -> if (!should_stop)
    -> ret = your_thread_function()
  -> do_exit(ret)
```

... So if `your_thread_function` simply returns, `do_exit` will be called with its return value. No need to do it yourself.

Comment: Well, the task struct is a global variable, so it can't go anywhere. But, does this mean if the standalone thread calls `do_exit()` (and therefore shouldn't call `kthread_stop`) it wouldn't need cleanup?

Comment: It can go places. If the task to which that task struct refers is completely done, and the task struct is freed by the exit path, the copy you have in your module data is just like a dangling pointer - you can't use it.

Comment: And yes, if you don't intend to `kthread_stop` your thread, it can call `do_exit` and normal cleanup will happen. _But_ if somehow your thread manages to outlive your module, you're in trouble.

Comment: Alright, if the cleanup is done, it's fine. I have made sure in `cleanup_module` to wait until the threads have returned. I have been bitten by it already.

Comment: Just to make sure, `kthread_stop` does wait for the thread to complete, too. It's a pretty nice wrapper. But I guess it might not be well suited to your use-case.

Comment: Ouch! Why wouldn't it wait? Doesn't the `wait_for_completion` do that?